# Intel IPP: unresolved external symbol _ippiResizeGetSize_8u@32

Tags: c++, unresolved-external, intel-ipp

I am having an odd issue and think there is a simple answer to that but I guess I just can't see the forest because of all the trees.

I am trying to compile a program using Intel IPP (Visual Studio 2015) and get the following error message:

```
unresolved external symbol _ippiResizeGetSize_8u@32
```

I added the appropriate folders to the project properties, which did not work. So just to be on the safe side I just copied all static libs and the corresponding header files into the folder where to code of the program lies. It does find the header files but I am also getting the above error. The libs are added as dependencies. I have set IPP so that it uses single-threaded static libraries.

What am I doing wrong here? It seems to be straightforward.

Thank you

Pat

Answer (score 0):

All unresolved symbol error come from VS linker. Basically, it means that you haven't added to linker "input" property the static library, which resolves the required external name.

In your case it is IPP image processing library, i.e. "ippimt.lib" (of the latest IPP versions), or "ippi_l.lib" of IPP v.7.x.

You can add the full name of ippi* library to "input" property, or add IPP library directory to the "general/additional directory" property of VS linker and name of the library file to "input" property. You don't need to copy static libraries to working directory, it doesn't work.

Regards, Sergey